# Why I am getting an error with plotly line chart

Tags: python, pandas, plot, plotly, plotly-dash

I am new to Plotly and was trying to plot the below pivot table using a Plotly line chart. My code is given below. The error is also attached here.

May I know where I went wrong

[image: Table]

```
  # create traces
    trace0 = go.Scatter(
        x = df_50_08_16_PVT['Device_ID'],
        y = df_50_08_16_PVT['NoiseLevel[dB]'],
        mode = 'lines+markers',
        name = 'Noise Level'
    )
    trace1 = go.Scatter(
        x = df_50_08_16_PVT['Device_ID'],
        y = df_50_08_16_PVT['SPEC_MAX'],
        mode = 'lines+markers',
        name = 'SPEC_MAX'
    )
    data = [trace0, trace1]  # assign traces to data
    layout = go.Layout(
        title = 'Line chart showing three different modes'
    )
    fig = go.Figure(data=data,layout=layout)
    pyo.plot(fig, filename='line1.html')
```

[image]

As Rob mentioned,I used Index.get_level_values(level) and graph is coming but not in an expected way. Please see my obtained and expected graph below
[image: Obtained]

Expected
[image: Expected]

Comment: looks like **Device_ID** is a part of a multi-index. this line of code will fail standalone `df_50_08_16_PVT['Device_ID']`. look into using https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html

Comment: This is a multi-indexed pivot table.

Comment: yep - my point.  so you can't refer to part of an index as if it is a column

Comment: changed X axis like this ' x = df_50_08_16_PVT.index.get_level_values('Device_ID')' is this fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- you have not provided sample data so I simulated
- your initial error was a straight **pandas** coding error.  You need to refer to values in indexes using [get_level_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html)
- your chart is *spikey* after a straight switch as multiple y-values share the same x-axis value
- resolved this by just using index position (`reset_index().index`)
- now need to build x-axis to include **Device_ID**
- finally fix up **hovertemplate**

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# question has no data, generate some...
df_50_08_16_PVT = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.DataFrame(
            index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
                [
                    [f"{h}_{n}" for n in np.random.randint(1000, 2000, 4)],
                    list("abcdefghijklmnop")[0 : random.randint(4, 15)],
                ],
                names=["Device_ID", "filler"],
            )
        )
        for h in ["SF", "TT"]
    ]
).pipe(
    lambda d: d.sort_index().assign(
        **{
            "NoiseLevel[dB]": np.random.uniform(-97, -102, len(d)),
            "SPEC_MAX": np.random.uniform(-96.5, -97, len(d)),
        }
    )
)


# build array has first instance of Device_ID and every other value empty string
s = (
    df_50_08_16_PVT.index.get_level_values("Device_ID")
    .to_series()
    .groupby("Device_ID")
    .cumcount()
)
ticks = np.where(s == 0, s.index, "")

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Scatter(
            x=df_50_08_16_PVT.reset_index().index,
            y=df_50_08_16_PVT[c],
            mode="lines+markers",
            meta=df_50_08_16_PVT.index.get_level_values("Device_ID"),
            name=c,
            hovertemplate="(%{meta},%{y})",
        )
        for c in df_50_08_16_PVT.columns
    ],
    layout={
        "title": "Line chart showing three different modes",
        "xaxis": {
            "ticktext": ticks,
            "tickmode": "array",
            "tickvals": df_50_08_16_PVT.reset_index().index,
        },
    },
)
fig
```

[image]

Comment: This code is a lot of learning for persons like me. May I know what that array 'S' and 'ticks' are doing here

Comment: https://plotly.com/python/tick-formatting/#tickmode--array defines how arrays need to be built to achieve labels on x-axis that we want.  `ticks` is that **ticktext** `s` is a series I use to be able to build this array

Comment: May I know what is happening here " ticks = np.where(s == 0, s.index, "") "

Comment: How " meta=df_50_08_16_PVT.index.get_level_values("Device_ID")" is mapped to X axis

Comment: this is the note "finally fix up hovertemplate".  Need values to use in **hovertemplate**